# Linked Digits-POTW

Tags: calculus

The number 34 685 contains 5 digits and we say its digit length is 5. The
left-most digit of 34 685 is 3. Each pair of consecutive digits, 34, 46, 68 and 85,
forms a number which is divisible by either 17 or 23.
The left-most digit of an integer with digit length 100 is 3. This integer also has
the property that any pair of consecutive digits forms a number which is divisible
by either 17 or 23. How many such integers are there?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't think this is difficult, there aren't that many two digit multiples of $17$ or $23$ to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Big hint: consider the possible final digits of two digit multiples of $17$ and $23$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the only consecutive pairs the number can contain are $17,34,51,68,85$ and $23,46,69,92$ ...

[image]
Repeat the sequence $34692$ $19$ times and then there are two possible endings
The two possibilities are
\begin{eqnarray*}
34692 34692 \cdots 34692 \\
34692 34692 \cdots 34685. \\
\end{eqnarray*}